# Hibernate. Duplicate entry '1' for key on save Object

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

When i try save third Object (*question3*) **Duplicate entry '1' for key 'UK_g74668cehn4p20wkd08q7ki1l'**.
Project structure:
**MainController**

```
@Controller
public class MainController {

    @Autowired
    private QuestionRepository questionRepository;

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String index(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("isAuthorized", false);
        model.addAttribute("currentPage", "homePage");

        Answer answer = new Answer("None", 1);
        Answer answer2 = new Answer("Easy", 2);
        Answer answer3 = new Answer("Meduim", 3);

        QuestionTheme question_theme = new QuestionTheme("Pain");
        QuestionTheme question_theme2 = new QuestionTheme("Symptoms");

        Question question = new Question(question_theme, "What hurts?", Arrays.asList(answer, answer2, answer3));
        Question question2 = new Question(question_theme, "Rotations?", Arrays.asList(answer, answer2));
        Question question3 = new Question(question_theme2, "Extension", Arrays.asList(answer));

        questionRepository.save(question);
        System.out.println("question.getId() = " + question.getId());
        System.out.println("question2.getId() = " + question2.getId());
        System.out.println("question3.getId() = " + question3.getId());
        questionRepository.save(question3);
        questionRepository.save(question2);

        return "index";
    }

}
```

**Answer**

```
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

@Entity
@Table(name = "answer")
public class Answer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private Long id;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String name;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private int weight;

    public Answer() {
    }

    public Answer(String name, int weight) {
        this.name = name;
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Answer{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", weight=" + weight +
                '}';
    }
}
```

**QuestionTheme**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "test_theme")
public class QuestionTheme {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private Long id;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String name;

    public QuestionTheme(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public QuestionTheme() {
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Question_theme{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

**Question**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "question")
public class Question {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private Long id;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
//    @JoinColumn(name = "question_theme_id")
    private QuestionTheme questionTheme;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.DETACH},
            fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "answer_list",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "question_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "answer_id"))
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private List<Answer> answerList;

    public Question() {
    }

    public Question(QuestionTheme questionTheme, String name, List<Answer> answerList) {
        this.questionTheme = questionTheme;
        this.name = name;
        this.answerList = answerList;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Question{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", questionTheme=" + questionTheme.getName() +
                '}';
    }
}
```

**QuestionRepository**

```
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public interface QuestionRepository extends CrudRepository<Question, Long> {
}
```

When execute **questionRepository.save(question3);** in **MainController** I get this error:

```
Completed initialization in 1 ms
Hibernate: insert into answer (name, weight) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into answer (name, weight) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into answer (name, weight) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into test_theme (name) values (?)
Hibernate: insert into test_theme (name) values (?)
Hibernate: insert into question (name, question_theme_id) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into answer_list (question_id, answer_id) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into answer_list (question_id, answer_id) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into answer_list (question_id, answer_id) values (?, ?)
question.getId() = 1
question2.getId() = null
Hibernate: insert into question (name, question_theme_id) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into answer_list (question_id, answer_id) values (?, ?)
2021-10-14 01:52:33.534  WARN 9559 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 1062, SQLState: 23000
2021-10-14 01:52:33.534 ERROR 9559 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Duplicate entry '1' for key 'UK_g74668cehn4p20wkd08q7ki1l'
2021-10-14 01:52:33.536  INFO 9559 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.e.j.b.internal.AbstractBatchImpl     : HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements
2021-10-14 01:52:33.561 ERROR 9559 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [UK_g74668cehn4p20wkd08q7ki1l]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement] with root cause

java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '1' for key 'UK_g74668cehn4p20wkd08q7ki1l'
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:117) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:953) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1092) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1040) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1350) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1025) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:61) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:197) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:46) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.recreate(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:1357) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.CollectionRecreateAction.execute(CollectionRecreateAction.java:50) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:604) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.lambda$executeActions$1(ActionQueue.java:478) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:684) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:475) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:344) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:40) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:99) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1362) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:453) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3212) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2380) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:448) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:183) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$300(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:40) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:281) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:101) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:562) ~[spring-orm-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:743) ~[spring-tx-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:711) ~[spring-tx-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:654) ~[spring-tx-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:407) ~[spring-tx-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-tx-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:174) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) ~[spring-aop-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy94.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at ru.brainrtp.tmedical.controller.MainController.index(MainController.java:70) ~[main/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:327) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:115) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:81) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:121) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:115) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:126) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:81) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:149) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:218) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:212) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:117) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:110) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:80) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:211) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:183) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:540) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1726) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_191]
```

Table **question** (i get it from DataGrip Documentation)

```
create table question
(
    id                bigint auto_increment
        primary key,
    name              varchar(255) null,
    question_theme_id bigint       null,
    constraint FKnmogm1ug9iu4q4m9oyg291ocu
        foreign key (question_theme_id) references test_theme (id)
);
```

Table **test_theme**

```
create table test_theme
(
    id   bigint auto_increment
        primary key,
    name varchar(255) null
);
```

Question: Why this error occurs and how to fix it?
I will also be grateful if you can point me out to my mistakes that I made when designing the project. Thank you!

--- Edit ----

```
create table answer_list
(
    question_id bigint not null,
    answer_id   bigint not null,
    constraint UK_g74668cehn4p20wkd08q7ki1l
        unique (answer_id),
    constraint FKkjnmyxuv540sqjlbbv2swl5nk
        foreign key (question_id) references question (id),
    constraint FKkwrnjix7ebw7frlua0ccja025
        foreign key (answer_id) references answer (id)
);
```

-- Edit how to fix my problem ---

1. Drop all tables from database
2. Change `@OneToMany` to `@ManyToMany` in `Question`
3. Restart application
   3.1) table `answer_list` no longer has unique keys :)
4. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You are saving the same instance `answer` multiple times for `question`, `question2` and so on.

If "None" should be saved for each question in a seperate Answer-record, you should create a new instance of the answer for each question.

```
Question question = new Question(question_theme, "What hurts?", Arrays.asList(createAnswer1(), createAnswer2(), createAnswer3()));
Question question2 = new Question(question_theme, "Rotations?", Arrays.asList(createAnswer1(), createAnswer2()));
Question question3 = new Question(question_theme2, "Extension", Arrays.asList(createAnswer1()));
private void createAnswer1(){ return new Answer("None", 1);}
private void createAnswer2(){ return new Answer("Easy", 2);}
private void createAnswer3(){ return new Answer("Meduim", 3);}
```

If the same record of "None" should be used for all the questions, first save each answer-record and use the return value of 'save(...)' to add them to the question (they are called `attached` after save).

```
    Answer answer = answerRepo.save(new Answer("None", 1));
    Answer answer2 = answerRepo.save(new Answer("Easy", 2));
    Answer answer3 = answerRepo.save(new Answer("Meduim", 3));
    Question question = new Question(question_theme, "What hurts?", Arrays.asList(answer , answer2 , answer3 ));
    Question question2 = new Question(question_theme, "Rotations?", Arrays.asList(answer , answer2 ));
    Question question3 = new Question(question_theme2, "Extension", Arrays.asList(answer ));
```

Comment: I understand correctly, to use the same "**Answer**" I have to save it first, for example like this:  
`Answer answer = answerRepo.save(new Answer("None", 1));`  
And then use "**answer**" in the constructor parameters when creating the object "**Question**"?

Comment: you understood correct, I extended the answer

Comment: Hi! I add this: `Answer answer = answerRepository.save(new Answer("None", 1));` and then: `QuestionTheme question_theme = questionThemeRepository.save(new QuestionTheme("Pain"));` and then: `Question question = new Question(question_theme, "What hurts?", Arrays.asList(answer, answer2, answer3));` and etc. for each **Question**. On second save (`questionRepository.save(question3);`). I have the same problem.

Comment: I found some problem. Hibernate create table `answer_list` full SQL i update in my post, check above it, please. 
Why `answer_id` is unique?

Comment: A solution to my problem was found.

Comment: @BrainRTP what was your solution? hit with the same problem